# Launch SMS from a mobile browser

Tags: mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending an SMS from mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848575/sending-an-sms-from-mobile-browser)

Is it possible to launch SMS/Texting application from a link in a website on a mobile browser? I doubt it's possible globally, but maybe it's possilbe for certain subsets (Blackberry, Windows Mobile, Google Android, etc etc), which we can detect and display.

Answer (score 7):

You can use wap wtai primite: `<a href="sms:1234567?body=hello world">Send SMS</a>`. It runs   on great majority of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it comes out of the box but you might be able to install a webkit widget on a recent series60 phone (samsung innov8, nokia n85...) to link the browser with the messaging application.

Answer (score 0):

iOS specific docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html

examples on other platforms such as Android here:
http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links/