# Sending an SMS from mobile browser

Tags: browser, sms

Is it possible for a mobile browser to send an SMS using the device's built-in capabilities? 
By that I mean, NOT using some online SMS services provider but actually making the mobile device send the SMS (same you would do using J2ME).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are lots of different mobile browsers out there, so I doubt that this is standardised. Safari/iPhone supports [SMS URIs](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4043-sms-api.html), which strikes me as a sensible approach to the problem and one that might be more widely supported than just the iPhone.

Based on the link (above) I found, and a comment from Zamel, I suspect this would work:

```
<a href="sms:+447787000000">SMS</a>
```

Although with a real phone number, and possibly escaping the + sign as %2B.

Comment: A small mistake, it should look like that:
<a href="sms:+447787000000">SMS</a>

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of the Opera Mini browser [provide a javascript interface](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#operamini-sms) for authoring SMS messages to be sent from the user's phone.

Also, some versions of Nokia's Symbian browser [include a javascript interface](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Web/web-apps/symbian-web-runtime/symbian-web-runtime-api-reference/platform-services-10-javascript-api-reference/platform-services-10-messaging-api/messaging-api-example.html#toc_messagingsamplejs) with similar functionality.

There might be others, but these are the only two I've found documentation for so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think a GSM modem is capable of acting as a SMS Gateway but you have to have the software installed on the modem to do this. You might also look into the [Carrier Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateways) Emails to SMS as another option. Example is AT&T number@txt.att.net

There are a couple of free services popping up these days like [ZeepMobile](http://zeepmobile.com/) that you might also want to look into.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to let the user send an SMS from his WAP browser in order to register to some service. He would get a confirmation SMS back.

Comment: ZeepMobile uses a HTTP post as a API to their SMS gateway. You could have the browser do the post and then the user would get a SMS text message. They do have ads at the bottom of the SMS message but it's the only service that offers a Short Code to send SMS messages on for free.

Answer (score 0):

No as a mobile browser is specifically built to render markup (html) documents.  Therefore, if you wanted to send SMS via a mobile browser it would call a web server page and send from the server NOT the mobile browser.

Mobile OS and their applications have quite a lot of limitations.  The closest you will see is the ability to hyperlink a phone # in a mobile browser to send a message but it will be handled via their SMS app not the browser.

Comment: You mean that the SMS will be sent by the device and not by the browser? That's OK, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible . You can call device functionality from browser . That is the way to go about  it . Webkit lets you do it

Answer (score 0):

Android and blackberry support
"mailto:" and "tel:".

Android supports "sms:" (and maybe iPhone, I don't have one :)) 
good luck and please post your result.

Answer (score -1):

It's a good thing that is not possible. It would be quite a security risk IMHO. I imagine spammers would be all over it.

Comment: You do not explain to him why and how. I understand what you mean though, but it's not clear enough. What he meant was "while allowing the user to validate", and you assumed "silently"...

Comment: WTH do I get a reputation hit for commenting on an answer :D ?

Comment: You don't. You get a reputation hit from downvoting my answer. See the FAQ.

Comment: Ah OK, not sure if it makes sense to me but whatever, as long as there is a reason :D