# Let user that use mobile browser to send the code of product they want by SMS

Tags: php, android, sms, symbian, mobile-browser

I'm going to use a method to let user that use mobile browser to send the code of the product they want by SMS. Currently I use something like:

```
<a href = 'sms:7xxxxxx?body=product-number23xx'>Buy product-number23xx</a>

<a href = 'sms:7xxxxxx?body=product-number24xx'>Buy product-number24xx</a>

<a href = 'sms:7xxxxxx?body=product-number56xx'>Buy product-number56xx</a>
```

It works on Symbian and Java platforms but it doesn't work correctly on all mobiles platforms like Darwin, Windows CE, Mobile OS. Any body can help me to say the sample code for other platforms?

I also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848575/sending-an-sms-from-mobile-browser) and I tried `mailto:` and `tell:` but the first one opens email client and the second one just add the number to that mobile contacts!

Comment: Well it is either implemented or not ):

Comment: Have you tried all this, http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links/

Comment: @MKJParekh Nice comment. Now I'm working on that

Answer (score 2):

Try "smsto:", some older browsers support it. I also believe that the detailed information regarding specific devices is available via WURFL (https://db.scientiamobile.com)

Answer (score 2):

iOS SMS URL scheme (sms://) doesnt support embed body !

Answer (score 2):

You need to update links for Android users.

i.e. if client browser is android then you need to configure link as below.

     `<a href="sms:+19725551212?body=hello%20there">SMS Me</a>`

Ref: [SMS URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android)

Comment: Not completely the answer but a helpful one. so i award bounty to you.