# Sending SMS from mobile browser with pre-composed message on Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: sms, uri, android-4.4-kitkat, mobile-browser

Pre Android 4.4 Kitkat, I was sending an SMS from the mobile browser with a pre-composed message and phone number by using something like:

< a href="sms:+1234567?body=helloworld">Send SMS < /a>

Upon clicking the link on the mobile browser, the default SMS app would be launched on the phone with the phone number and pre-composed message already entered. All the user would have to do is press send and the message would be sent. Testing using Chrome and the default browser on Android 4.1 - 4.3 seems to indicate this still works).

However on KitKat, the pre-composed message is not populated in the field, only the phone number. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching the same issue for a while and I couldn't find a positive answer.

[SMS URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android)

However, there seems to be an alternative: send the SMS from the server using PHP and a form, as described here:

[sending sms from a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234732/sending-sms-from-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: The link you provided by sending it using PHP requires the knowledge of the carrier before hand, which for my purposes we would not have. I think the purpose of using PHP to send an email with the sms information to the carrier url was to avoid having the user physically press send. 

I am completely okay with the message being pre-composed but not sent. For obvious security reasons it should be up to the user to send the text itself.The problem still lies in that the pre-composed body message is not populated (as it did before 4.4). I appreciate your help though.